# Using i18n string resources in Nativescript Android

Tags: android, internationalization, nativescript

I'm pretty new to nativescript. I'm trying to figure out how to use the string values from the strings.xml so i can localize my app.

My layout looks like this.

```
<StackLayout class="page">
    <label [text]="@string/a_value"></label>
    <Label text="Hello world with tap!" class="yellow"></Label>
    <button text="Tap me my friend" (tap)="tapTheButton()" class="red"></button>
    <label [text]="text" class="blue"></label>
</StackLayout>
```

The @string/a_value should get the string from the res/values/strings.xml file.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@string/string_name` is not a valid notation when describing NativeScript layouts as it's a strictly Android way of interpolating strings.

You could probably access the resource manager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) and get the string value for string with name `a_value`, and then data bind that to your label. That would only work on Android.

There is a NativeScript plugin done by the community that aims to make internationalization abstract, so that it works for both Android and iOS - nativescript-i18n.

Comment: Thanks, i took a look at the plugin and it worked for me. Cheers!